# Base "/" not found in Django

Tags: django

My django project `ornaments` has only one app called `balls`. I would like the server to point to its index when I do manage.py runserver but I get this error:

[image]

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
        path('balls/', include('balls.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='balls/', permanent=True)),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am also including the project structure. Please note that the string `ball` appears nowhere in my code (as per a search).

[image]

Comment: Your search included the templates as well?  You should include in your question the `balls.urls` as well as the `view`, and the `templates`.

Comment: '''from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]''' is `balls.urls` and yes, I serached everything inside the project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "server points to".  Either through a bookmark, or your template, you are requesting the path /ball, and the server is not finding that path.  What does your terminal display after you run `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I don't understand where 'ball/' is coming from. Why isn't it redirecting to 'balls/'?

Comment: I never mention anything called `ball` (with no `s`) anywhere in the codebase - I am confused.

Comment: UPDATE: so, even if I start a new project with a different name and an app with a different name and do absolutely nothing when I do `python manage.py runserver` and navigate to 127.0.0.1 I get: `Not Found: /ball/
[10/Jan/2022 10:04:44] "GET /ball/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2475` @R.Uziel ...

Comment: Again, to troubleshoot I'd need to see more of your code.  Your `views`, your `templates`, and `settings.py`.  Edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was a problem with the browser's cache (all three browsers I tested) and even curl. Very weird but now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, you're sending requets to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ball` and this URL not found on given path  `path('balls/', include('balls.urls'))` so try to go to this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/balls`

Comment: Yes @Yassin that did work. What I cannot understand is where `/ball` can possibly come from.

Comment: You have just two URLs on  your app `balls/ ` and `admin/`

Comment: Yes. I want to server to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/balls.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but if you want to point **ball/** to something in your`views.py` you need to add **path()** to it.